# Saving statmodels Tukey hsd into a Python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am looking for a way to save the results to save the results of the Tukeyhsd into a pandas dataframe. see below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import statsmodels.stats.multicomp as multi 

 mcDate = multi.MultiComparison(df['Glucose'], df['Date'])
 Results = mcDate.tukeyhsd()
  print(Results)

    Multiple Comparison of Means - Tukey HSD,FWER=0.05
=============================================
group1 group2 meandiff  lower   upper  reject
---------------------------------------------
  A      B     20.35    7.388   33.312  True 
  A      C     -3.85   -16.812  9.112  False 
  B      C     -24.2   -37.162 -11.238  True 
---------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I do not have access to your data, so I can't replicate the result. I used randomised data instead, just to show that this works. All you need to add to your code is the pandas import, and the last line creating the data frame.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import statsmodels.stats.multicomp as multi
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Random Data.
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.choice(['A','B','C'], 50)
y = np.random.rand(50)

# DataFrame.
mcDate = multi.MultiComparison(y,x)
Results = mcDate.tukeyhsd()
print(Results)
```

Produces the following table:

```
============================================
group1 group2 meandiff  lower  upper  reject
--------------------------------------------
  A      B     0.1506   -0.07  0.3712 False 
  A      C     0.1105  -0.1278 0.3487 False 
  B      C    -0.0401  -0.2865 0.2063 False 
--------------------------------------------
```

And, this is how you get the data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=Results._results_table.data[1:], columns=Results._results_table.data[0])

print(df)

group1 group2  meandiff   lower   upper  reject
0      A      B    0.1506 -0.0700  0.3712   False
1      A      C    0.1105 -0.1278  0.3487   False
2      B      C   -0.0401 -0.2865  0.2063   False
```

I struggled with this for a while myself, and eventually found the solution by reviewing methods for the object, like this:

```
dir(Results)
```

Comment: This doesnt work for me. I get an error `'SimpleTable' object has no attribute '_results_table'` 
Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: In statsmodels version 0.14 `tukey_df = pd.DataFrame(data=Results.summary().data[1:], columns=Results.summary().data[0])`

Answer (score 2):

As an update to @vander's answer, and to address @thentangler's comment, in statsmodels 0.12.1 the table's data is accessible as `Results.data` rather than `Results._results_table.data`.

The conversion of `Results` to a dataframe then becomes:
`df = pd.DataFrame(data=Results.data[1:], columns=Results.data[0])`.