# Annotation of tukey results into an sns lineplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, statsmodels

I would like to annotate results I received from a tukey test into my `lineplot` in `seaborn`.

Basically, the `lineplot` is showing a change over time. Which is why I computed the tukey test to see which `timepoints` show a significant difference.

I did create a `lineplot` with `seaborn` which looks identical to this (here generated from random `datapoint`s):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Define the ages
ages = [8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 20, 24]

# Define the DataFrame
data = {'Age': [], 'Size': []}

# Generate the data
for age in ages:
    for _ in range(5):
        data['Age'].append(age)
        # Generate random size, increasing with age
        data['Size'].append(np.random.randint(1 * (age - 7), 20 * (age - 7)))

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Display the DataFrame
df
```

lineplot:

[image: lineplot]

Afterwards, I used the following lines of code to compute a tukeyhsd, to compare the different ages in regards to their size:

```
from statsmodels.stats.multicomp import pairwise_tukeyhsd
tukey_results = pairwise_tukeyhsd(df["Size"], df["Age"])
print(tukey_results)
```

Hence, I received the following result:

```
Multiple Comparison of Means - Tukey HSD, FWER=0.05  
=======================================================
group1 group2 meandiff p-adj    lower    upper   reject
-------------------------------------------------------
     8     10     21.6 0.9979 -104.7336 147.9336  False
     8     12     60.2 0.7358  -66.1336 186.5336  False
     8     14     91.0  0.286  -35.3336 217.3336  False
     8     16     72.6 0.5445  -53.7336 198.9336  False
     8     20    127.4 0.0471    1.0664 253.7336   True
     8     24    188.0  0.001   61.6664 314.3336   True
    10     12     38.6 0.9566  -87.7336 164.9336  False
    10     14     69.4 0.5949  -56.9336 195.7336  False
    10     16     51.0 0.8549  -75.3336 177.3336  False
    10     20    105.8 0.1474  -20.5336 232.1336  False
    10     24    166.4 0.0043   40.0664 292.7336   True
    12     14     30.8 0.9857  -95.5336 157.1336  False
    12     16     12.4 0.9999 -113.9336 138.7336  False
    12     20     67.2 0.6295  -59.1336 193.5336  False
    12     24    127.8  0.046    1.4664 254.1336   True
    14     16    -18.4 0.9991 -144.7336 107.9336  False
    14     20     36.4 0.9672  -89.9336 162.7336  False
    14     24     97.0 0.2216  -29.3336 223.3336  False
    16     20     54.8 0.8096  -71.5336 181.1336  False
    16     24    115.4 0.0907  -10.9336 241.7336  False
    20     24     60.6   0.73  -65.7336 186.9336  False
-------------------------------------------------------
```

My question now is, if there is a way to automatically annotate the significant p-values into the plot?

I already tried to continue, by filtering the rows which are significant. In this way I could than with a for loop automatically filtering the significant groups and `p_values` and add them with a for loop to a plot.

However, when I try to filter the data, I just get an empty `dataframe` which does not contain any data.

```
tukey_results = pd.DataFrame(tukey_results.summary())
tukey_results_significant = tukey_results[tukey_results[6] == True]
```

I would appreciate any recommendations you might have.

Comment: See [Saving statmodels Tukey hsd into a Python pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40516810/saving-statmodels-tukey-hsd-into-a-python-pandas-dataframe) about converting to a DataFrame. `tukey_df = pd.DataFrame(data=tukey_results.summary().data[1:], columns=tukey_results.summary().data[0])`.  For annotations, Seaborn refers to using matplotlib functions.